# Code for rename column is erasing a column from my data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, rename, plyr

When compiling my code to add a column and rename input values the end result is one column less, meaning my code is erasing the column I want to rename. The dataframe `Teste` before renaming has 13 columns, after using the function `Lotacao_Small` I get 12 columns. I do not find the error?

```
link <- url("https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat/salarioDocente/master/Teste/Dez2018SerT.csv")
Teste <- read.csv2(link, header = TRUE, encoding = "ASCII", skipNul = TRUE)
source("https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat/salarioDocente/master/Teste/Lotacao_Small.R")
Teste <- Lotacao_Small(Teste)
sessionInfo()


R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.2 plyr_1.8.4     tools_3.5.2    yaml_2.2.0     Rcpp_1.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function attempts to rename factor levels in column ORG_LOTACAO, which does not exist in your dataframe. The resulting error is assigned to your column LOTACAO, which makes it disappear.

Try running just the code embedded within the function to see the error it generates.

Comment: The problem is that I do not get any errors, it works the same way! And besides, as I have to modify multiple databases with a huge number of rows, I can not remove the levels that are not present in this table!

Comment: Please read my answer again. The problem is not is that you get a warning ("The following `from` values were not present in `...`"). The problem is that you run the function "revalue" on a variable that does not exist in your dataframe. The first argument of the function "revalue" has to be an *existing* factor variable.

Comment: True, I did not notice that I was applying on a nonexistent variable. Ctrl + c and Ctrl + v do this! Thank you

Comment: No problem! I had a hunch that you had missed that, I should have been clearer. (I've been there myself, once you've missed it it's almost impossible to "see" ...)